# How to optimise data retrieval and inter-controller data sharing with AngularFire automatic binding?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Say I have

1. a list view+controller that displays a list of item names and
2. a detail view+controller thats shows detail for an item.

How would I use angularfire (preferably with automatic three way binding) in a way that does not fetch the same data twice?

Because controller#1 would have already fetched the items AND their details when the `(itemsListRef).$bind($scope, 'items');` statement executes. In controller#2, `(itemDetailRef,).$bind($scope, 'itemDetail')` would then fetch item detail data that again that has already been fetched in controller#1.

One option that comes to mind : An angular service could be used to fetch the items data once and then share the data between controllers, but I am not sure how angularfire three-way automatic binding would play into this, or if it would even work. Your thoughts/advise on this? Any other options? What would be the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase client is smart enough to use a local cache if it exists. Firebase instances are singletons for each base Firebase URL, so attaching multiple listeners at varying paths in the same Firebase will *not* result in unnecessary network activity.

I recommend creating a `$firebase` reference in a service, and then using a 3-way data bind for the details of the item in a controller. For example:

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"]);

myapp.factory("ItemService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
  return $firebase(itemsListRef);
}]);

myapp.controller("DetailCtrl", ["$scope", "ItemService", function($scope, items) {
  items.$child(itemId).$bind($scope, 'itemDetail');
}]);
```