# Adding multiple listeners to the same Firebase in an iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an iOS app that uses Firebase and stores data in dictionaries in the following basic heirarchy...

```
Users > Projects > Boards
```

(Boards are children of projects, which are children of users)

I have listeners attached at the Project and Board level - I've initialize a Firebase reference with URLs (using initWithURL) for each of these.

The data stored at the Project level is pretty small and updated infrequently (basically things like the project name) but the data at the Board level is pretty significant in size and will be updated very frequently - it's a live drawing app, so basically anytime a user has his/her finger on the board, it's sending and receiving data.

MY QUESTION:  Is there a huge drawback to having 2 listeners like this, one of which is on child that is being updated constantly while the parent is relatively static?  Should I move the data at the Boards level out of this hierarchy so that the listener on the Project level doesn't get fired off simultaneously?  Is there any more or less data being transferred, and will I be unnecessarily charged more this way (especially by calling initWithURL twice)?

Comment: I think I may have just found my answer here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html
Looks like I'm doing it right, but maybe if somebody could just confirm, since it feels like I'm double dipping here and possibly pulling more data than necessary with the listeners...

Comment: Since fetching Projects also fetches any Boards under that path, you should move the data on the Boards level to its own path so you can freely fetch Projects without the additional overhead, then fetch boards as needed. It's a simple matter of bytes.

Comment: Isn't there a local cache that's used if certain data under the same parent is unchanged? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824796
Does it fetch the entire tree or not?

Comment: I think you're right: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/structuring-data.html
Says there to keep things flat and that the whole shebang is fetched even though elsewhere it says the opposite.  Thanks for the tip!